# Why model both UI and logic as html?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Given the following definition for the Polymer project:

*The Polymer project provides a framework for building custom html elements. The framework is built upon emerging browser standards that allow for modularization and encapsulation of html elements.*

Polymer seems to take this to extreme: *everything is a component.*

What are the benefits of using an html element to make a web request?
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax

Comment: You have too many different questions. Ask a specific question, never ask multiple questions on one post. Also, a question should have code, otherwise it's usually not a good fit for SO

Comment: Also, we avoid coarse language, no need for "why in the hell"

Comment: Thanks Juan; removed some extra questions and removed the curse word :O

Comment: The question is still way too broad "what is the purpose for X" will always get closed.  You need to have an actual problem, not just a question for idle curiosity.

Comment: Benefits of having a component make an Ajax call? You don't have too worry about it, just give it a URL and it will load the data for you, think a table with a url property

Comment: What if I need to share that data with other parts of my UI?

Comment: Whoever learns JavaScript *after* learning HTML will soon find that JavaScript is a better place for logic to live, but at least the HTML API was able draw that new programmer into that new world of logic called programming.